# Support Gallery link to pages

Tags: permalinks, images, themes

Hi i am new in wordpress 
i am try to show small gallery (like services) on home page and i want them to link them with pages not with post. currently i am working on theme. it has a services option but i am not able to link those with pages. i can link them with posts. please suggest any plugin
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What about using [Page Links To](https://wordpress.org/plugins/page-links-to/)? Install this plugin, go to the edit screen of the post "Project Management" and then link that post to any page you want. That way you can redirect the post to any page you want.

Not a perfect solution but may work for your setup.